# Different equation general solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fundamental-solution

Hi I am looking for the general solution of the following problem:

$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$$
Initial condition: $u(x,0) = -x $ and $u(0,t) = 0 $  and $u(1,t) = 0 $

I tried to separate the function $u$ like this $u(x,t) = f(x)g(t)$ to find a basis of solutions.

$$ \frac{g'}{g}(t) = \frac{f''}{f}(x)$$

gives me that both ratio are equal to the same constant $\kappa$ for all $x$ and $t$. $\kappa = -\lambda^2 <0$ otherwise the solution explodes or is 0.

$g(t)=ae^{-\kappa^2  t}$ and $f(x)=be^{\kappa x  } + ce^{-x\kappa }$

$u(x,t)=ae^{-\kappa^2 t}(be^{\kappa x} + ce^{-\kappa x})$

$u(0,t) = 0 $ gives $b = -c$

From that I can not find any solution but the null function.

Could you help me find the general solution? Thank you

Note that:

This problem is obtained from that one: 
$$ \frac{\partial v}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2}$$
Initial condition: $v(x,0) = 0 $ and $v(0,t) = 0 $  and $v(1,t) = 1 $

where I substracted the stationnary solution $u = v - v_{\infty}$ with $v_{\infty}(x)=x$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is not right. If

$$ \frac{g'}{g} = \frac{f''}{f} = -\kappa^2 $$

Then, equivalently

\begin{align} g'(t) &= -\kappa^2 g(t) \\ f''(x) &= -\kappa^2f(x) \end{align}

The solution is

\begin{align} g(t) &= ae^{-\kappa^2t} \\ f(x) &= b\sin(\kappa x) + c\cos(\kappa x) \end{align}

and

$$ u(x,t) = e^{-\kappa^2t}\big(B\sin(\kappa x) + C\cos(\kappa x) \big) $$

where I've combined the constants: $B = ab$, $C = ac$

The boundary condition $u(0,t) = 0$ gives $C = 0$

$$ u(x,t) = Be^{-\kappa^2t}\sin(\kappa t) $$

The boudnary condition $u(1,t) = 0$ gives

$$ \sin(\kappa) = 0 \implies \kappa = n\pi $$

where $n$ is an integer.

Since every value of $n$ will satisfy the equation, we can use the law of superposition to write the full solution in series form

$$ u(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty B_n e^{-n^2\pi^2t}\sin(n\pi x) $$

The last step is to apply the initial condition and find the corresponding Fourier series. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you for your very useful answer.
The initial condition is $\forall x\geq 0, u(x,0)=-x$
$$ u(x,0) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty B_n \sin(n\pi x) =-x$$

When I tried to find the $B_n$ as a Fourrier coefficient:

$ B_n= \int_0^{\infty} -xsin(n\pi x)dx $

 I used the boundaries of the domain of definition of my intial conditions but I think the boundaries of my integral are wrong because the integral does not converge.

Comment: Any time you're given two points, i.e. $x=0$ and $x=1$ as your boundary conditions, you assume the domain is only between those two points.

Comment: Assuming x is between 0 and 1, I get: $$B_n= \int_0^1 -x\sin(n\pi x)dx = [\frac{x\cos(\pi n x)}{\pi n}]_0^1 - \int_0^1 \frac{\cos(n\pi x)}{n\pi} dx =\frac {(-1)^n}{\pi n} - 0 -[\frac{x\sin(\pi n x)}{\pi n}]_0^1 =\frac {(-1)^n}{\pi n} $$ Does that seems right to you? I validate your answer btw

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you have an explanation for the separation of the function u(x,t) in g(t)f(x)? Also do you have a link or explanation for the law of superposition over the possible n? Understanding this two points will help me understand intiutively why this solution is the unique solution of the problem. I will probably make another thread about it tho =)

Comment: There isn't really an intricate reason for assuming a production solution, other than, it's something that works and produces a solution. It's more or less just an educated guess.

Comment: As for your other question, that's more of a separate problem, you shouldn't focus on proving why "this" solution is the unique solution. Instead, you can prove that if *a* solution exists and can be found (regardless of the method), then it's unique. Something like: Suppose the equation has two distinct solutions $u_1$ and $u_2$, and $u_2-u_1=w$, then $w=0$ is the only possibility.